# Bearpaw fletching jig deluxe - am I able to just change the clamps from right winged to straight?

Tags: gear, archery

I've a [Bearpaw deluxe fletching jig](http://www.byronferguson.com/Bear_Paw_Fletching_Jig/p2045234_9415137.aspx).

> Simple and easy to use, the jig is made of a high-quality combination
>   of metal and space-age plastic. Change from 3 to 4 or even 6 fletch
>   settings with the flip of a switch. No more set screws, allen
>   wrenches, or cumbersome knobs to turn!

[image: jig]

I've bought it with a right wing clamp. However, I want to switch back to "straight" again.

Am I able to just buy a [straight spare clamp](http://www.merlinarchery.co.uk/spare-clamp-for-bearpaw-deluxe-fletching-jig-straight-clamp.html) and use it on the jig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the Bearpaw one but I own a couple of jigs and on both, the clamp is attached by a magnetic bit and I can swap clamps without problems.

In addition of changing clamps, both jigs have a couple of screws/bolts where the clamp is attached so you can adjust the offset.

I've seen same features in all other similar jigs I've come across so I truly believe you should be able to just change the clamp with no problems specially with the "deluxe" bit in the name. :)

Furthermore, I shoot compound for target and barebow recurve for field and hunting so I fletch my arrows straight for target and right helical for field/hunting. I only have a right helical clamp and use it to get my fletching straight for target adjust the offset on the jig to compensate the helical. You should also be able to do it too. :)